# Does plumbing code allow free standing Fiberglass bathtub with supply line shutoffs under the tub?

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance, bathtub, shutoff

I am in the middle of a master bathroom remodel and am installing a free standing fiberglass bathtub with supply lines and drain going into the wooden subfloor.

The bathtub is hollow in that it is designed to "drop" over the supply/drains which are hidden under the tub.  The faucets are mounted onto the tub with the flexible lines running from the faucets to the copper supply lines. Here is an image showing hot/cold supplies coming up through the floor:

[image]

I have pulled a plumbing permit from the city and want to ensure that this complies with plumbing building code.

I am planning on running 1/2" copper under the subfloor and and installing shutoff valves for both hot/cold supply lines above the floor, but under the tub.  To install the tub, I will set it 4.5" above its final resting place on 2x4's, get the drain and supply lines connected (there is a special "drop in" drain fixture for this purpose), open the shutoff valves and lower the tub by removing the 2x4's.  Then after leveling it, checking for water leaks, etc. it will have a bead of silicone run around the skirt to keep it from sliding around.

Anybody see any code violations?  I had one plumber tell me I needed "accessible" shutoffs for the bathtub per code, but after perusing the national plumbing code and Florida Building Code section 606, I can't see any requirement for shutoffs to bathtubs or showers.

I will probably go over to the building department as well, but figured I would ask here.  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the shut offs will not be handy after.  Can you not place them so they can be used if needed, without ripping half the room out?

Comment: I placed mine in the line before they went into the bathroom. one for hot and one for cold. I did this for each of my sinks etc in my home. I have a full basement so it was no problem. The inspector told me it was not necessary but it will helpful if I have any problems. I used 1/4 turn ball valves.

Comment: @crip659 The shutoffs will be handy for install or If I  need to disconnect (eg to replace the faucets).  In either case the tub will need to be raised to access. I can't think of any situation where I would need to use them unless I am raising the tub.

Comment: We like to think our plumbing will never leak, but usually find that is not the case.  Raising the tub to use the shut offs does not sound like fun at two in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the building inspector who came out to do the topout plumbing inspection and apparently there is no building code requiring shutoffs for a free standing tub.  The plumber who told me shutoffs were required was wrong.

That being said, I did end up putting a single set of hot/cold ball valves in a wall where the supplies enter the bathroom for both the shower and the tub and added a plastic access door in the drywall to hide them.  With today's shower valves that have replaceable cartridges it makes sense to have these shutoffs for both the shower and tub so that the faucets/shower valves can be maintained without shutting off the water to the entire house.